# Why does the error "DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION" happen？

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-10-upgrade

I installed Windows 10 and upgraded it automatically it to version 1511.10856.589 (with all of its latest update packages). This problem occurs at a random time (about 4~5 hours).

I uploaded my [dmp file](http://share.weiyun.com/90d793446f25e8d67bc239538cde5baa)

I did the following things before this started occurring:

1) I used PE and found a hidden partition after installing the Windows 10, and then I delete the partition and merged it to the C (main partition where Windows 10 is).

2) Asus Computer with one drive of touch-pad that cannot be upgraded successfully, after uninstalling the old version from the control panel and re-upgrading it, it succeeded!

[image]

**PS：I never met the problem when using Windows7, and by the way, when upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, nothing happens. This problem ONLY happens when I format C and install directly windows 10....**

[image]

Comment: update to BIOS 203: https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X550LC/HelpDesk_Download/ and look what happens

Comment: OK,I'll see the final result and my BIOS is upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error most often occurred for me when attempting to install a driver for a device that was no longer connected or was a corrupted driver. Other such causes could be outdated firmware for SSDS/other devices not supported by your operating system.

Check device manager for unknown devices and see if they have any updated drivers for those devices.

Comment: I've also upgraded that, and I'll see the final result:-)

Comment: the calltack shows noting storage related only internal kernel function

Comment: @magicandre1981: All in all, I've upgraded all the drivers (including bios). I'll watch whether the situation happens or not later. And have you analyzed my file?

Comment: @DongWei yes, I looked at the dmp